# Does Lp convergence for absolutely continuous function imply convergence a.e.

Tags: convergence-divergence

My question is the following. If a sequence of absolutely continuos functions $\{f_n\}$ converge to zero in $L^p(S)$ ($S$ has finite measure), does it follow that the $f_n \to 0$  everwhere ?

Comment: Do you know an example when the $f_n$ are not absolutely continuous?  You should be able to modify it by replacing the jumps with sufficiently steep line segments.

Comment: Certainly not **everywhere**. Consider e.g. $$f_n:\left[0,1\right]\to\mathbb{R},x\mapsto\begin{cases}
n\left(\frac{1}{n}-x\right), & x\in\left[0,\frac{1}{n}\right),\\
0, & x\geq\frac{1}{n}.
\end{cases}$$ Note that all $f_n$ are Lipschitz, hence absolutely continuous, but $f_n(0) = 1$ for all $n$. Even **almost** everywhere is not true, as indicated by @NateEldredge.